# How to refine the shape of an SKSpriteNode for tap gestures?

Tags: swift, skspritenode, uitapgesturerecognizer

In my app I create mutiple **SKSpriteNodes**, gems. *Code snippet 1*

When I loop through nodes from the main scene in a tap gesture, *Code snippet 2*, the gems register in a perfect square shape even though they are not. *Screenshot enclosed* I have highlighted all areas that the orange gem registers in a tap as white.

Since the gem is itself not a square, I'd like to know if there is a way refine its shape so it would only show up in the list of nodes in UITapGestureRecognizer if the orange part is tapped. I have even tried by assigning it a **physicsBody**. But that made no difference.

Code Snippet 1

```
class MyGem : SKSpriteNode{

    init(iColor : Gems) {
        fileName = "\(iColor)_gem"
        let skTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: fileName)
        super.init(texture: skTexture, color: .clear, size: .zero)
        self.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
        self.size = CGSize(width: myGV.gemSize.width, height: myGV.gemSize.height)
        self.zPosition = theZ.gem
        self.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0 )
        self.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        self.name = "gem"

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
         fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Code Snippet 2

```
   @objc func tappedView(_ sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {

        if sender.state == .ended{
            var post = sender.location(in: sender.view)
            post = self.convertPoint(fromView: post)
            for node in self.nodes(at: post){
                if let touchNode = node as? MyGem 
                    print("touched gem")

                    highliteGem(theGem: touchNode, clearAll: false)
                    return
                }
```

[image: screenshot]

[image: Here is how the image appears in Xcode]

Comment: Maybe trying an SKCropNode could work, [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/games/how-to-crop-a-sprite-using-skcropnode) is a short tutorial

Comment: Seeing as the gems are just rotated squares, could you not just have an orange square, then rotate it 90 degrees?

Comment: @JohnL This is just for development. When I am done it will be a much fancier graphic.